# Ajax request fetching data from database and return it

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make a simple Ajax request that in the controller can fetch the data from the db and return it. Right now I have this code on the view:

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajaxRequest',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            password: password,
            email: email
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.lots);
            alert(data.success);
            $("#id").append(data.lots);
        }
    });
});
```

And this code on controller:

```
public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $result = DB::select('select * from users');
    $enc = json_encode($result);
    $ht = "<h3>TESTE</h3>";

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Got Simple Ajax Request.', 'lots' => $enc]);
}
```

How can I echo every row of the variable $enc on the view ?

Comment: I would suggest looping through `data.lots` and then appending each item to the page inside a HTML element. have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm new to java script and ajax requests, could you help me out how to do the loop ? @ADyson

Comment: Also. I don't know your specific framework / controller code, but I _suspect_ that you don't actually need to do `$enc = json_encode($result);` - there's a chance this may be double-encoding your data, because I'd guess that `response()->json` also encodes the array you pass to it as JSON as well. So `return response() - json(['success' = 'Got Simple Ajax Request.', 'lots' = $result]);` is _probably_ all you need. (If the data is double-encoded you'll have trouble looping it, because `lots` will still be a string when it arrives in your JS code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to `json_encode()` the `$result` variable as Laravel will handle this for you. The code you have at the minute would technically mean that you would need to decode the data again.

Secondly, you don't actually need to use `response()->json()` since returning an array from a route/controller method will automatically get converted to JSON anyway. This is more of an FYI than something you actually need to do.

Change your controller method to:

```
public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'success' => 'Got Simple Ajax Request.',
        'lots'    => DB::select('select * from users'),
    ];
}
```

Then to loop through the results you could use a `for` loop:

```
success: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.lots.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.lots[i]);
    }
}
```

or since you're using jQuery [$.each(...)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.lots, function (index, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```